# socket connection with angular is not working

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to create an application using socket with Angular and node.js as backend application. In the backend I can see that connection is getting established/disconnected but not able to read events.

this is my server side **node.js** code:

```js
const server = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
io.on("connection", (client) => {
  //console.log(client);
  client.emit("message", "hellow world");
  client.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    client.emit("message", "hellow world");
  });
  client.on("disconnect", () => {});
});
server.listen(3000);
```

this is my service file added in **Angular** codebase:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  private socket: Socket;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
    this.socket.on("connect", function () {
      console.log("Connected!");
    });
  }

  // EMITTER
  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    // this.socket.connect();
    console.log(this.socket);
    this.socket.emit("message", { message: msg });
  }

  // HANDLER
  onNewMessage() {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.socket.on("message", (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        observer.next(msg);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

While logging this.socket, i can see the following object:

```
acks: {}
connected: false
disconnected: true
flags: {}
ids: 0
io: Manager {nsps: {…}, subs: Array(1), opts: {…}, _reconnection: true, _reconnectionAttempts: Infinity, …}
nsp: "/"
```

Whats wrong with my code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why you didnt' ngx-socket-io instead of socket.io-client is more dedicated for angular project , https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-9-realtime-chat-example-with-nodejs-socketio-and-websocket/

Comment: @RebaiAhmed: I used that also, that was also having the same issue.

Comment: error by the varsion differance

Comment: You mean version difference ?

Comment: Hi @Era did you solved it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client and server socket versions were different which was causing the issue. Changing to the compatible socket version at both the sides solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use socket-io-client with version 2.3.1 and try.